# Where is the guard that drops the "Bearer of sorrows"?

Tags: pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous

According to the PAthfinder:Wrath wiki, the Bearer of Sorrows drops from "Senior guard in the Fleshmarket in act 4".

[image]

But in the Fleshmarket there is no "Senior guard" - there are slave traders, two regular guards, a pirate and various traders that you can attack via dialog option. But no "senior guard".

Answer (score 1):

On my second playthrough, I've managed to get this weapon, but it seems that the "senior guard" only spawns when you start a big fight in the Fleshmarket:

I've attacked first Raggy, Black Mask and Dyunk the Slave trader, but the guards did not interfere. But when I've attacked Sarzaksys (the owner of the Fleshmarket), every NPC around became hostile (so it is wise to get rid of the other traders first), with exception of the Venture-Captain Gristoff, who can help you if you donate 50k gold to the Pathfinder society.

Since the whole fight is quite chaotic, I can only vaguely pinpoint the location of the Senior Guard, as spawning somewhere between Raggy's shop and the shadow-slaver selling possessed slaves (I think that his name is Kerz).

It is worth noting that my fight was part of the "[Where is my dragon](https://pathfinderwrathoftherighteous.wiki.fextralife.com/Where%27s+My+Dragon?)?" quest for the Azata path, which gives you a huge bonuses when fighting in the Fleshmarket.